# Is it possible to catch Win7 multitouch events, convert them to mouse and keyboard events and send them to another application?

Tags: c#, windows-7, events, forwarding, multi-touch

I have following Situation: I have a special 3D program which I need to make able to react on multi-touch events without changing the program itself. Therefore I need a mapper program, which receives the multi-touch events of Windows 7, converts them in corresponding mouse and keyboard events and send this emulated events to the 3D program, so that it can process those events.

I have already read and tried a lot and my current approach is to have an almost transparent overlay window over the 3D programm to catch multi-touch events. But this is also the problem, I'm unable to manage to forward the generated mouse events to the underlying 3D programm in a usable way. Right now I used pinvoke functions like mouse_event, SendMessage and so on, but none of them worked for me. Since I always had to bring the 3D program to front, send the event and afterwards I needed to put my mapper programm to front again. This works quite crappy.

So my question is more or less, is there a nice working approach to do the things I mentioned above? Or at least a nice way to send mouse and keyboard events to processes in the background?

Hope anyone could give me a hint or suggestion....

Here are the way I simulate mouse clicks right now:

```
    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {    
        Point position = this.PointToScreen(new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));

        //Simulate the mouse event on the given position 
        this.Visible = false;

        Cursor.Position = position;
        mouse_event(Convert.ToUInt16(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);   
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point position = this.PointToScreen(new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));

        //Simulate the mouse event on the given position 
        Cursor.Position = e.Location;
        mouse_event(Convert.ToUInt16(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        this.Visible = true;
    }

    //Get a handle to the mouse event manager
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe have a look at [InfoStrat.VE - Bing Maps 3D for WPF and Microsoft Surface](http://bingmapswpf.codeplex.com/).
They made the Bind maps control usable for touch.

Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to direct mouse/keyboard events to a particular process in Win32.  That being said, however, you *might* be able to get this approach to work:

1. Register your mapper window as a touch window to get touch events.
2. Add a handler for [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618(VS.85).aspx) in your message loop, call DefWindowProc() to get the default handler, and then convert any HTCLIENT returns to HTTRANSPARENT.  This will cause Windows to pass any mouse events through your window, onto the underlying window.
3. This probably won't work if your mapper window lives in a separate process from your client program; if that's the case, you'll have to do some hacking with [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956(VS.85).aspx).  I don't recommend this, incidentally, as merged thread queues are very prone to bugs.